# What does && mean in void *p = &&abc;

Tags: c++, c, gcc, operators

I came across a piece of code `void *p = &&abc;`. What is the significance of `&&` here?
I know about rvalue references but I think `&&` used in this context is different. What does `&&` indicate in `void *p = &&abc;` ?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: I'd also like to know where you've seen this.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

[`&&` is gcc's extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels%20as%20Values) to get the address of the label defined in the current function.

`void *p = &&abc` is illegal in standard C99 and C++.

[This](http://www.ideone.com/AX6Dw) compiles with g++.

Comment: Now imagine how better programmers everyone would be if gcc had -pedantic by default. Then people would learn C instead of irrelevant information about gnus.

Comment: What a hack. If they invent a new syntax for label pointers, they should invent a new type for it as well instead of using `void*`.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: Whoever downvoted probably disapproves of the feature and is taking it out on you.

Comment: @Lundin: Same can be said of most compilers. `__forceinline`? `__declspec(naked)`? One of my favourite MSVCisms is: `template<typename T> class X { friend T; }`, which is invalid C++03.

Comment: Second link is dead.

Answer (score 96):

## How to find it out

That's the address of a label and it's a feature specific to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).

```
int main(void) {
    void* startp;
s:
    startp = &&s;
    printf("the assignment above starts at address %p\n", startp);
    return 0;
}
```

You could have figured it out yourself by testing:

```
int main(void) {
    void* startp;
    int a;
    startp = &&a;
    printf("startp=%p\n", startp);
    return 0;
}
```

In which case GCC says:

> error: label ‘a’ used but not defined

## Under the hood - assembly

You need to know assembler to really understand this, but I'll try to explain you what an address of a label means.

After the OS loads the .exe file from the disk, a component of the operating system called "the loader" (windows has the "PE Loader", linux has "ELF loader" or maybe even others, if they're compiled in the kernel), it does a "virtualization" of that program, turning it into a process.

This process thinks it is the only one in RAM and it has access to the entire RAM (that is, 0x00000000-0xFFFFFFFF on a 32-bit machine).

(the above is just a short overwiew of what's happenning, you really need to learn assembly to understand it fully, so bear with me)

Now, the label in a source code is basically an address. "goto label;" does nothing else than a jump to that address (think about the [instruction pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) in assembly). This label stores this RAM address, and that's how you can find out that address.

After you've learned ASM, you'll realize that that address points to a instruction within the `.text` section of the executable. The `.text` section is the one which holds you program's (binary) code to be executed.

You can inspect this with:

> objdump -x a.out

## A practical example

As described in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html), you can use this to initialize a jump table. Some [scanner generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) like [re2c](http://re2c.org/) (see the `-g` parameter) use that to generate more compact scanners. Maybe there's even a [parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) employing the same technique.

Comment: Compile with -std=c99 -pedantic.

Comment: Pretty important to mention that it is a GCC extension, and not a core part of teh language

Comment: Thats pretty impressive Flavius.

Comment: i like this kind of answer, more people need to be taught how to find answers rather than just being told.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. Appreciated the Assembly related analysis.