# Kernel hacking methodology - how to find out where to hack the linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hardware, driver

I have a throw-away cheap laptop I'd like to twiddle around, a Thinkpad SL 500.

What bothers me are two leds, the one for wireless connectivity, and the one for hibernation, which don't light up at all, although they're functional, I've tried it on windows.

So I would like to write a kernel driver for them, nothing big, it just looks like a good idea to play around with the kernel.

My question is *what methodology should I follow systematically to find out what devices are responsible for those leds* (in general, not necessarily specific to my hardware), and what drivers are responsible for the other two leds that work, bluetooth and the battery indicator?

And when I say methodology, I really mean the methodology, step by step, with reasons for each step, like in the answer I've gave to someone else over here: [What does && mean in void *p = &&abc;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106493/what-does-mean-in-void-p-abc/6106586#6106586)

I am profficient at fgrepping through big code repositories, using static code analysers & co, but I think my lack of hardware knowledge hinders me on this problem.

PS: I'm using ArchLinux, so almost the latest kernel version.

Comment: I would like to know from the people voting it for being closed as "not constructive", what EXACTLY is not constructive? I'd like to write a very simple kernel driver, it looks constructive to me.

Comment: The problem may be (I didn't vote to close, and I even upvoted) that this is a very wide question. It's not off topic in my opinion but asking for " the methodology, step by step, with reasons for each step" may be a little out of the custom here.

Comment: Even though it's a programming question, it's very open ended and difficult to impossible to provide you with an authoritative answer that is both specific enough for your needs and general enough to be applicable to a wider audience.  That's why you're getting close votes.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I see in there: "However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK". I'll address this on meta, because the community seems poisonous to me.

Comment: Could be more on-topic on [unix.se].

Comment: @darvids0n UNIX C API and System Interfaces questions are on-topic, on Unix and Linux, but general programming questions are not.

Comment: @dystroy please help reopen it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thinkpad-acpi) might be a good place to start.  I believe that ACPI drivers are usually responsible for things like hibernate LEDs in laptops.  Where to go from there, I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do more research. +1

Comment: Sitting below that though, you'll probably have a system-management CPU - or maybe just raw devices - hanging of I2C.  I2C is nice and hackable from user-space.

Comment: Please help reopen the question.

Comment: @Flavius: See also [Writing an ACPI driver - an introduction](http://lwn.net/Articles/367630/) on lwn.net.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your question is appropriate on SO.

However, I would first try to guess what hardware do you have precisely. Commands like `hwinfo`, `lspci`, `lsusb` should help.

Then you could search the web for the outputs which might be relevant.

And you should know if your wifi is working on Linux, and if yes, with which drivers. If it is *ndiswrapper* you are probably out of luck.

Actually, you should have a precise understanding of your hardware as possible.

I would ask more precise questions on kernel or driver related lists.

Comment: It is a programming question, of course it's appropiate on SO.

Comment: My problem is, what do I do after I find out those "device ids"? Where to look after that? How to be sure the hardware information I've extracted are actually relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: You might google for these device ids, and if you are lucky you'll find something relevant. Otherwise, you'll need to reverse engineer everything...

Comment: But it is not a source code related question. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything" in  "reverse engineer everything"?

Comment: I mean that guessing the programmable aspects of a hardware device without any documentation is not fun. Try to improve the *nouveau* driver (for Nvidia graphic cards) if you want to feel what that means (I didn't try to improve *nouveau*, but I am using it and have reported a bug).

Comment: Please help reopen the question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried the [lenovo-sl-laptop driver](https://github.com/tadzik/lenovo-sl-laptop)? As far as I can see, it supports the LEDs, and allows you to control at least the lenovocare led via the `/sys/class/leds/lensl::lenovocare/` files. See the [README](https://github.com/tadzik/lenovo-sl-laptop/blob/master/README) file for details.

Note that the driver may be available in the Arch repos already, you don't necessarily need to recompile the driver yourself.  Sorry for not being much clearer, but I myself have neither SL500 nor Arch, so I cannot verify the details. If you're interested in the various ways you can use scripts to fiddle with the leds, I might be of assistance. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please help reopen the question.

Comment: Why should we reopen the question? it is much too broad and vague...