# What is "label" in the error message for C programming after error compilation?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, compilation, label

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a = 13; 
    const int **pp = &&a;
    return 0;
}
```

Look at the above code.

I know it is not right.

However, my question is about the **error message** that I don't understand.

I thought the error message would contain things like **"lvalue unary operand required"** or something.

After **cc -std=c11 test.c**, I got this:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:2: error: label ‘a’ used but not defined
  const int **pp = &&a;
```

I think **a** should be called a **variable** or **identifier** which is defined already by using **int a = 13;**

What is **label** in the error message for C programming language after error compilation?

Comment: What does address of the address of 'a' even mean in this context? What compiler is giving you this error message?

Comment: I get `C2059 syntax error: '&&' StackOverFlow d:\repo\wip\ctest\stackoverflow\stackoverflow\source.c 11`.

Comment: I suspect the compiler you are using has some extension where the address of a label can be taken with `&&`. In unextended C, `&&` is a single operator; it is not `& &`. You can only take the address of an object; you cannot take the address of an address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does && mean in void \*p = &&abc;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106493/what-does-mean-in-void-p-abc)

Answer (score 3):

You've stumbled across a non-standard GCC feature called [Labels As Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).

Change your code to the following and see what happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int a = 13; 
    void *pp = &&a;
    goto *pp;
    return 0;
a:
    printf("ooooops\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It's basically a way to use `goto` labels as values, in the sense that you can assign a label to `void *` pointer, and then use that pointer in a `goto` statement.

This is not standard C, to make sure you don't use any non-standard features set `-std` to `-std=c99` or what ever standard you'd like to use.

Comment: Much more to the point — change the code to `void *pp = &a;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think you're missing the point. Question clearly asks what is `label` in the error message and not how to fix it.